# Setting Windows Accent Color as WPF Window Background through XAML and listen to Accent Color Change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-10

I'm creating a WPF project which uses the windows 10 Accent color as background for my WPF Main Window. I was able to get the windows Accent Color using `GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference()`, `GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName()` & `GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx()` and I was able to use it as my window background. But the problem is that i was not able to change the Background automatically when the Accent Color is Changed (I must restart to change the background).

Here is the code that I use:

*AccentColors.cs*

```
public static class AccentColors {

    private static Brush systemAccentBrush;

    static AccentColors() {
        InitializeBrushes();
    }

    public static void InitializeBrushes() {
        SystemAccentBrush = CreateBrush(GetColorByTypeName("ImmersiveSystemAccent"));
    }

    public static Color GetColorByTypeName(string name) {
        var colorSet = NativeMethods.GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference(false, false);
        var colorType = NativeMethods.GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(name);
        var rawColor = NativeMethods.GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx(colorSet, colorType, false, 0);

        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(rawColor);
        return Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2]);
    }

    private static Brush CreateBrush(Color color) {
        var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        return brush;
    }

    #region Brushes
    public static Brush SystemAccentBrush {
        get {
            return systemAccentBrush;
        }
        private set {
            if (!object.Equals(systemAccentBrush, value)) {
                systemAccentBrush = value;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

The `InitializeBrushes()` function is called from `WndProc` `WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED` which helps me to set `SystemAccentBrush` to the current system **Accent Color** and it works perfectly.But When i'm setting the `SystemAccentBrush` as background for a control it doesn't change based on the **Accent Color** Change (*But the Brush Color is changing*).

Here is the code that i used to set SystemAccentBrush as the background for a Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="container" Background="{x:Static common:AccentColors.SystemAccentBrush}">
</Grid>
```

I think the problem is related to this :

```
{x:Static common:AccentColors.SystemAccentBrush}
```

So i tried setting it as Dynamic source like this:

```
{DynamicSource {x:Static common:AccentColors.SystemAccentBrush}}
```

Then the background disappears.

**Is there any way to overcome this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`x:Static` markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension) is for static references and does not pick up any changes at runtime.

> References any static by-value code entity that is defined in a Common Language Specification (CLS)–compliant way.

If you create static properties that change at runtime, you have to use a binding and implement a static equivalent of the `PropertyChanged` event similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This feature is supported since WPF 4.5 and there are [two different ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/getting-started/whats-new?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-to-static-properties) to implement it.

### Event Handler

Change your property as below and  create an event `SystemAccentBrushChanged` for your property. Raise the event in the setter of `SystemAccentBrush` with `null` and `EventArgs.Empty`.

```
private static Brush systemAccentBrush;
public static Brush SystemAccentBrush
{
   get => systemAccentBrush;
   private set
   {
      if (Equals(systemAccentBrush, value))
         return;

      systemAccentBrush = value;
      SystemAccentBrushChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}

public static event EventHandler SystemAccentBrushChanged;
```

### Static Property Changed Event

Change your property as below and create an event `StaticPropertyChanged` and raise it with the property name that was changed. This event can be used with different properties.

```
private static Brush systemAccentBrush;

public static Brush SystemAccentBrush
{
   get => systemAccentBrush;
   private set
   {
      if (Equals(systemAccentBrush, value))
         return;

      systemAccentBrush = value;
      OnStaticPropertyChanged();
   }
}

public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
   StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

### Binding the Static Property

In order to bind the static property to pick up the change notifications, you have to use a `Binding` with `Path` and parentheses to access the class member. If you omit `Path`, the XAML parser and the designer will throw and error.

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Path=(common:AccentColors.SystemAccentBrush)}">
```

---

A final note on this: Although static bindings with property changed notifications are supported this way, you might want to think about migrating your static class to a singleton. This way, you could make  `SystemAccentBrush` a non-static property, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and bind the property as usual, without any special syntax or custom static events.

Comment: Thankyou very much it worked pretty well and your answer was very much understandable. you definitely deserve an upvote.